# Insert NULL Rows Into SQL when Missing Data

Tags: sql, sql-server

Esteemed StackOverflow Community -

I work at Initech as a direct report to Mr. Lumbergh.  I have the weighty responsibility of ensuring that all employees are reading, and more importantly, complying with our TPS reports.  Of paramount importance is that all employees enthusiastically bring dishes for company celebrations.  It helps give the company some flair.

To ensure everyone is fully expressing themselves, I have the following SQL output:

```
  ID | Name | Location | Holiday | Time | DishCnt | TastedGood
  1    Bill    1st Fl.    Easter    AM       3          Yes
  1    Bill    1st Fl.    Easter    PM       3          Yes
  1    Bill    1st Fl.    Kawanza   AM       2          Yes
  6    Sameer  1st Fl.    Easter    AM       1          No
  6    Sameer  1st Fl.    Easter    PM       2          Yes
  6    Sameer  1st Fl.    Kawanza   AM       1          Yes
  7    Peter   1st Fl.    Easter    AM       1          No
  7    Peter   1st Fl.    Kawanza   AM       2          No
```

How can I determine what people *actually do* here?  What I would like is a table that includes null rows for any missing combinations of holiday and time.  From the example above, I would see that everyone *should* have a dish count listed for the following combinations:

```
Easter / AM
Easter / PM
Kawanza / AM
```

If the table were structured as needed, it would look as follows:

```
  ID | Name | Location | Holiday | Time | DishCnt | TastedGood
  1    Bill    1st Fl.    Easter    AM       3          Yes
  1    Bill    1st Fl.    Easter    PM       3          Yes
  1    Bill    1st Fl.    Kawanza   AM       2          Yes
  6    Sameer  1st Fl.    Easter    AM       1          No
  6    Sameer  1st Fl.    Easter    PM       2          Yes
  6    Sameer  1st Fl.    Kawanza   AM       1          Yes
  7    Peter   1st Fl.    Easter    AM       1          No
**7    Peter   1st Fl.    Easter    PM     NULL         NULL**
  7    Peter   1st Fl.    Kawanza   AM       2          No
```

As we can see, a new row has been added for Peter identifying the missing dish.  It appears he may not be the straight-shooter some claim him to be.

Our SQL administrator is somewhat of a no-talent ass clown, so any help you are able to provide in converting the first table into the second would be tremendously appreciated.  Specifically, it must:

- Identify all combinations of Holiday and Time present in the original table.
- Generate a new table with all of the original rows intact, plus any missing observations as NULL.

---

Update Regarding Efforts Thus Far:

This has been a bit of a case of the Mondays for me.  I've dug into this quite a bit, but to no avail.  I strongly suspect the solution will involve finding distinct combinations of Holiday / Time in the original table, and then somehow joining it back to the original table such that any missing combinations are added as NULLS.  My O'Reilly SQL Cookbook seems to get close, but I can't wrap my head around what I would join the two tables on such that missing observations would be added.

In R, which will ultimately consume this data, I could account for it via some of Hadley's packages (e.g. tidyr), but I'm hoping to address it in SQL - For which I have much less experience.

Comment: Almost amusing enough to give a +1 just for the movie reference, but to help it would be good to see that you'd actually tried to solve it and ask specific questions about your solution; rather than a "do this for me" ... even if wrapped in a funny little context.

Comment: Correct; first you'll have to find distinct Holiday /Time combinations. I suppose you know how to do this? Selecting columns from a table and making the result distinct? Then you need to combine this result with all employees. So select distinct employees from the table (or get them from an employee table) and then cross join the two sets. Now continue with your plan: join the original table. You must outer join it. That's it. Try it and come back in case you have concrete issues with this. (In that case show the query so we can tell you where you have it wrong.)

Comment: You said SQL-output. Is this one single table or the output of a query which joins a couple of tables? Do you have the statement? Maybe you could provide some statements to get the tables with some testdata? I would create a table with the Holiday and Time combinations. Another one for the employees. Then you can `CROSS JOIN` those two. You get a combination of all Employees for all holidays with times. Finally I would  LEFT JOIN the Table with the DishCnt and TasteGood info. (Edit: Thorsten was faster)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM Holidays H
CROSS JOIN Times T
LEFT JOIN Report R ON H.HoludayKey = R.HolidayKey AND T.TimeKey=R.TimeKey
```

- The `CROSS JOIN` gives us all the possible combinations of holiday/time.
- The `LEFT JOIN` says to give us all of the holiday+time records, even if there isn't a matching TPS Report row

Comment: Thanks all!  I ultimated choose to account for this in R as referenced above, but Jonathan's answer would also have gotten us close.